# CountA Function in Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that adds checkboxes to worksheets with the text "benefits" in the sheet name.

I need a checkbox in row 3 for each column that has text in row 5.  Each worksheet will have a different number of columns.

The code below works, but sets and then uses the columnCount for the first worksheet for all the worksheets.

I think I have the right code, but have it placed in the wrong order??

```
    'Checks for the text "Benefits" in the sheetname.
    'If true then runs AddCheckBoxesRange Macro to add selection checkboxes for each plan.
    Sub CheckSheets()
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            If LCase$(sh.Name) Like "*benefits*" Then Call AddCheckBoxesRange(sh)
        Next sh
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub


'Macro CheckSheets looks for the text benefits in sheetname, if it exists it calls this macro
    Sub AddCheckBoxesRange(ws As Worksheet)
    'add Form checkboxes
    Dim c As Range
    Dim myCBX As CheckBox
    Dim rngCB As Range
    Dim strCap As String

    Dim columnCount As Integer
    columnCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("5:5")) + 1
    Set rngCB = ws.Range("B3", ws.Cells(3, columnCount))

    strCap = "Select Plan"

    For Each c In rngCB
      With c
        Set myCBX = ws.CheckBoxes.Add _
          (Top:=.Top, Width:=.Width, _
           Height:=.Height, Left:=.Left)
      End With
      With myCBX
        .Name = "cbx_" & c.Address(0, 0)
        .LinkedCell = c.Offset(37, 0) _
            .Address(external:=True)
        .Caption = strCap
      End With
    Next c

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to qualify the columnCount otherwise it will always look at the ActiveSheet.

Change

`columnCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("5:5")) + 1`

to

`columnCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("5:5")) + 1`

Comment: That works!!  Thanks so much for the explanation as well.  New to this - so understanding why will help with future work.

Comment: Good, and thank you for accepting the answer - so many people don't.